# jstree wont save state if the data not defined in core?

Tags: jstree

I have an application that is using jstree. In this app I have set the “data” section of core to an empty array as you see below:

```
$("#jstree")
    .jstree({
        "core": {
            "data": [],
            "check_callback" : true,
            "themes": {
                "theme": "default",
                "icons": false
            }
        },
        "plugins": [ "state" ]
    })
```

I am using jstree.create_node() to add new nodes to the tree programmatically as new data is sent to the browser. When I refresh the page the tree does not maintain the state even though I am using the state plugin. However if I set the `data` field in core to an actual JSON object, it would work as described in the `state` plugin:

```
 "core": {
            "data":[{"id":"a", "parent":"#", "text":"nodeA"},{"id":"b", "parent":"a", "text":"nodeB"}],
            "check_callback" : true,
            "themes": {
                "theme": "default",
                "icons": false
            }
```

Is there a difference between the two ways of doing it that affects the state plugin? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, yes thank you it makes sense. I need to do a few things differently for it to work but I understand it better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it just works.

```
jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": [
          {"id":"a", "parent":"#", "text":"nodeA"},{"id":"b", "parent":"a", "text":"nodeB"}
        ],
        "check_callback" : true,
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "icons": false
        }
    },
    "plugins": [ "state" ]
})
```

Check out [codepen](http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/dGLeWQ), try adding a new node or expand/collapse node and then reload the page. The state will be remembered.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for the quick response. In the example you provided: if you add a new node and select it, the state does not get saved

Comment: Hi, please check the codepen http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/dGLeWQ again. I added a div to show updated content of localStorage

Comment: What state plugin won't do is save the nodes themselves. It just keeps their ids.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. here is the steps for what I’m experiencing with this code. Add new node > select the new node. the log you have will show the following: `{"state":{"core":{"open":["a","b"],"scroll":{"left":0,"top":0},”selected":["j1_1"]}},"ttl":false,"sec":1455741009139}` indicating the new node is selected. When you reload the page, this new node is not in the tree anymore but the state is maintained. However it can’t select `”j1_1”` since it is not in the tree.

Comment: Yes, that is how it is expected to work. You will have to save the tree with new nodes to server. Then on page reload, they will be all shown and their state will be updated from info kept in localStorage.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Is there a way to add new nodes to the `data` field in the jstree core dynamically?

Comment: Why would you do that? The `data` property is for initialization only. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I see, I have data coming in every now and then creating new nodes for client end. I was trying to avoid extra caching of data but it seems necessary.

Comment: You are fine on the client end. Create new nodes as you receive new info for that from server. State plugin will keep status. Then you can save your tree back to server once the user has finished doing whatever he was doing. Or do it regularly, at some intervals, if there is possibility that he might just abandon the page. At the next load states of nodes will be pulled from storage as far as whatever you load has same ids.

Comment: oh ok this makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. Does this mean the tree is redrawn every time time there is a new node that comes in from the server side?

Comment: How does your info come from server? You probably have some ajax callback where you have access to ajax response text or json. So inside that callback you should explicitly create new jstree node and fill it with the info you got from server, e.g.: `$("#jstree").jstree().create_node('#', nodeLabel)`, where a new node with label from variable `nodeLabel` will be appended to the root node.

Comment: it is a bit different for this application. I'm using browserify to do everything from the client end. So my client has listeners that get triggered every time something is written on a specific path (this can be considered an external database). However the data that comes in is not "jstree ready", so I manipulate it and give it `id`, `parent`, `text`, etc. then call `jstree().create_node` with the new node. This is why i was thinking of caching it on client end.

Comment: If you don't want to or can't send updated tree to server you could use localStorage for whatever info you want to store client side. E.g. jsonify the whole tree and put it there under some specific key. Then restore the tree from there on page reload.